# CI_SESSION Query for desired id to find active user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I have `ci_sessions` table in my database, and when a user is logged in, their information saves in this table.  I want to check that if I give particular `user_id` then it show me if that this user is active or inactive.

I want query in CodeIgnter's active record format, not basic MySQL format.

For example:

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('ci_sessions');
 $this->db->where('user_data','');
 $this->db->get();
```

In my `ci_sessions` table, the `user_data` column contains all info, including user_id.  I want search this column `where user_id = 'my_given_id'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `user_id` that is stored in the session data by 
`$this->session->userdata('user_id');`

If you want to get a particular session from the `ci_sessions` table then you have to first retrieve the `session_id` from the `userdata` and then you can query it.

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ci_sessions');
$this->db->where('session_id', $session_id );
$this->db->get();
```

**Edit:**
If you want to query all stored sessions in the database and search for a particular `user_id` inside it, you have to first get all the data stored inside the table, unserialize the `user_data` and search inside it for the `user_id` you are looking for.

Comment: actualy i m doing this in a foreach loop and in foreach loop i have user_id that is coming from other table so i want to use that id to display one by one either that user is active or not

Comment: the method u told it display only current user id getting from $session_id

Comment: Sport Billy i was unable to find user id 
i do following i returns all info of all users how can i find only desired id if i give id 1

Comment: $user_id=1;
$this->db->where("user_data <>","");
$query = $this->db->get('ci_sessions');
$result=$query->result();
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
   $user_data=$row->user_data;foreach (unserialize($user_data) as $k => $v) 
    {
                 if($k=='user_id') 
     {
                     $str="$v"; 
                 }
             }
      }

Comment: @AyshaAli: So does `echo $str;` print out the user ids?  If so, just compare that to the one you want.  `if($k=='user_id' && $v==$user_id) { $str=$v; }`

Comment: @AyshaAli, only this loop helps you to search inside the CI_Session table. I think, if we try with the help of regular expression, we can develop a function to search inside ci_sessions.

Comment: Thanks alot Rocket Hazmat...:)